# It is possible to call function or calculate in C preprocessor step?

Tags: arrays, c, macros, preprocessor

I want to make array whose length is `(int)log(macro constant)`
like

```
#define MACRO_NUM 100
int arr[(int)log(MACRO_NUM)];
```

But as you know, MSVC doesn't support variable-length array. So, declaring array, I can't use variable or function at index of array.
It means every value determined in run-time couldn't become index of array. So I thought that preprocessor should do some kind of calculation before compilation if to do this possible.

So my question is

1. Is my inference right?
2. So is there any ways to make preprocessor calculate? Or preprocessor can do just only replacements.

I know there's another ways like dynamic allocation with pointer etc, but, I just wander ,as a student, It is possible way to do this with array and macro constant when variable-length array is not supported.

Comment: By `log`, do you mean "logarithm base 2"?

Comment: yes. but, I don't think it matters whether it's based 2 or e or 10

Comment: @GeoChoi It might not matter but it probably does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the preprocessor doesn't do calculations, only substitutions and the other usual preprocessor stuff.

However, you can sometimes get a similar effect as follows.  Pretty much anywhere in C that a compile-time constant is needed, you can use an arbitrary arithmetic expression whose operands are constants (which will be evaluated by the compiler, not the preprocessor).  And a macro can be a convenient way to wrap such an expression, especially if it would otherwise be awkwardly long.

As a trivial example, you can do

```
#define SQUARE(x) ((x)*(x))
int foo[SQUARE(6)];
```

After preprocessing, this reads `int foo[((6)*(6))];` and the compiler defines an array of length 36.  The calculation was done by the compiler, not the preprocessor, but the effect is much the same.

Now `log` isn't generally a function that the compiler can evaluate at compile time, but you can fake it:

```
#define MY_LOG(x) ((x) < 10 ? 0 : (x) < 100 ? 1 : (x) < 1000 ? 2 : .....)
```

with as many more `?:` as you need until you've exhausted the range of `int` or `long` or whatever.  For log base ten it'll only be at most 10 or 20.  And then you can do

```
#define MACRO_NUM 100
int arr[MY_LOG(MACRO_NUM)]
```

and get an array of length 2.

Just be careful that you don't ever use `MY_LOG` with an argument that has side effects!

Comment: If MY_LOG had side-effects, you couldn't use it as an array dimension in a C implementation without VLAs.

Comment: @rici: No, right.  I'm just saying, if you need a log function for a runtime computation elsewhere in your code, don't use this macro for that purpose if the argument has side effects.  Actually, even if it doesn't have side effects, the `MY_LOG` macro is probably less efficient than other ways of computing the log.

Comment: ilogb is probably the most efficient if you don't need a compile-time constant.

Answer (score 1):

If `MACRO_NUM` is guaranteed to be a compile-time constant (such as 100) and by `(int)log(MACRO_NUM)` you mean "the largest *k* such that 2<sup>*k*</sup> ≤ MACRO_NUM", then it can be done (but not by getting the preprocessor to do a computation, which is not really possible):

***Note**: See below for a much more compact version.*

```
#define LOG_MACRO_NUM ((MACRO_NUM >= (1UL<<1)) + \
                       (MACRO_NUM >= (1UL<<2)) + \
                       (MACRO_NUM >= (1UL<<3)) + \
                       (MACRO_NUM >= (1UL<<4)) + \
                       (MACRO_NUM >= (1UL<<5)) + \
                       (MACRO_NUM >= (1UL<<6)) + \
                       (MACRO_NUM >= (1UL<<7)) + \
                       (MACRO_NUM >= (1UL<<8)) + \
                       (MACRO_NUM >= (1UL<<9)) + \
                       (MACRO_NUM >= (1UL<<10)) + \
                       (MACRO_NUM >= (1UL<<11)) + \
                       (MACRO_NUM >= (1UL<<12)) + \
                       (MACRO_NUM >= (1UL<<13)) + \
                       (MACRO_NUM >= (1UL<<14)) + \
                       (MACRO_NUM >= (1UL<<15)) + \
                       (MACRO_NUM >= (1UL<<16)) + \
                       (MACRO_NUM >= (1UL<<17)) + \
                       (MACRO_NUM >= (1UL<<18)) + \
                       (MACRO_NUM >= (1UL<<19)) + \
                       (MACRO_NUM >= (1UL<<20)) + \
                       (MACRO_NUM >= (1UL<<21)) + \
                       (MACRO_NUM >= (1UL<<22)) + \
                       (MACRO_NUM >= (1UL<<23)) + \
                       (MACRO_NUM >= (1UL<<24)) + \
                       (MACRO_NUM >= (1UL<<25)) + \
                       (MACRO_NUM >= (1UL<<26)) + \
                       (MACRO_NUM >= (1UL<<27)) + \
                       (MACRO_NUM >= (1UL<<28)) + \
                       (MACRO_NUM >= (1UL<<29)) + \
                       (MACRO_NUM >= (1UL<<30)) + \
                       (MACRO_NUM >= (1UL<<31)))
/* If you want to handle 64-bit numbers, change 1UL to 1ULL
 * and continue the pattern up to 63.
 */
```

[Live on coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b38c11cb4b1643d)

This can be made much more compact using the [Boost preprocessor library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html), which unlike most of Boost works with both C and C++. It's a separate header-only library, so it can be installed independently by just copying the directory of header files. That reduces the above ugliness to:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat_from_to.hpp>
#define CHECK_POWER(Z,I,V) + ((V) >= (1ULL << I))
#define ILOGB(C) (BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO(1, 32, CHECK_POWER, C))

/* Declared at file scope to show that the macro produces a
 * compile-time constant; static VLAs are not allowed
 * even on compilers which implement VLAs.
 */
int arr[ILOGB(4127)] = {0};
int main(void) {
    printf("array has %zu elements.\n", sizeof arr / sizeof *arr);
}
```

[Live on coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/be8aae2af61fc335)

Comment: wow, I never thought about like this. lol. that's why you asked me base of logarithm. thanks

Comment: @GeoChoi: I added the (much shorter) BoostPP implementation, which would not have been so easy to do with bases other than 2.